# Setting the camera matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, camera, camera-matrix

Is it possible to set the camera view and projection matrices in MATLAB? With "view matrix" I refer to the position and orientation of the camera in space (actually, the inverse of it, but this is just a detail), and "projection matrix" refers to the matrix which projects the 3D points to 2D screen coordinates (either orthographic or perspective). It seems to me that in MATLAB you can control the camera only by using the "low-level camera properties":
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f4-44406.html
This is not sufficient for me as I would like to set the matrices myself, as it is done in OpenGL/DirectX/etc.

Comment: I haven't seen anything that lets you set the matrix directly. Could you work around it by creating a function that decomposes the view matrix into `eye,center,up` vectors and wraps the existing the low-level calls?

Comment: I tried to do so, but I can't figure out how the view, target, and zoom parameters depend on eachother, especially the zoom parameter...

Comment: Take a look at http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/